# Zend Framework: Redirect from Controller Plugin which is more efficient

Tags: zend-framework

i seen from [here](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-components-13/model-view-controller-mvc-21/redirect-plugin-1611.html) 2 ways to redirect from a controller plugin ... i wonder which is more efficient. i am wondering in the 2nd method, it maybe slower because the response is created? what happens in the 1st method tho? it will redirect immediately?

```
$request->setModuleName('default')
        ->setControllerName('search')
        ->setActionName('form')
        ->setDispatched(false);
```

or

```
$this->_response->setRedirect('redirecturl');
```

Comment: $this->_redirect('url'); should be the fastes (header redirect)

Comment: that will be when i am in a Zend_Controller_Action class right?

Comment: yepp only works in controllers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first method is an application redirect: You define that the requested operation is within another controller, so the same http request is used to execute the action.

The second method is an http redirect: The http-response will have an http-location-redirect, so the client will fire a second a http-request to get the result.

The first is definetly the most efficient.

PS: You can call the forward-method of the controller to dispatch another action.

Comment: What if you wanted to also change the displayed URL?

Comment: i am in an controller plugin is forward available? with the request object, can i add a response code eg. HTTP 401 for login required? @Alister Bulman: if i think `_redirect('/page1')`?

Comment: @AlisterBulman: The second option (http redirect) will change the URL  
@JiewMeng: Forward helper is not available in controller plug-in, only in the controller itself. You can set the HTTP response code by calling `$this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode()` method and modify the headers by calling `$this->getResponse()->setHeader()` method.